# Topology open close set

Tags: general-topology

I have a quick question

In $\mathbb{R}$ let $$S \subset \mathbb{R}$$

If S is not open then must it be a closed set?

I think no because if it not closed means its complement is open. But how do I show this?

Comment: Show this by exhibiting a set that is neither open nor closed.

Comment: The set $[0,1)$ is neither open nor closed.

Comment: You can show a statement is false by exhibiting a single counterexample.

Comment: What if I have if S is not closed then must it be open?

Comment: if for all S, "S not closed $\to$ S open", then by taking complements "S not open $\to$ S closed"... so, do the logic.

Answer (score 1):

In $\mathbb R$ the only subsets which are open and closed at the same time are $\varnothing$ and $\mathbb R$. This is due to the fact that $\mathbb R$ is *connected*.

To show that, say $\varnothing \subsetneq A\subsetneq \mathbb R$, and that $A$ is both open and closed,
and say $x\in A$, $y\not\in A$, and assume that $x<y$. Then defined
$$
s=\sup\{t\in A : t<y\}.
$$
If $t\in A$, then $(t-\varepsilon,t+\varepsilon)\subset A$, for some $\varepsilon>0$, as $A$ is open, and hence $t$ is not the supremum of the set above, a contradiction. If $t\in \mathbb R\smallsetminus A$, 
then as $\mathbb R\smallsetminus A$ is open, there exists an $\varepsilon>0$, such that $(t-\varepsilon,t+\varepsilon)\subset \mathbb R\smallsetminus A$. Again leads to a contradiction, as in such case $\sup\{t\in A : t<y\}\le t-\varepsilon$.